# Failed attempt on eigencomposition of a matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm studying the module Algebra, and was reading the course book "Álgebra. Aplicaciones a Teoría de Códigos". I got stuck on this problem because I couldn't satisfy the conditions given for a matrix.

**Question:** Given the eigenvalues $\lambda_1=1$, $\lambda_2=3$ with the associated autosubspaces $V_1$ and $V_2$ defined as:

$V_1 \equiv \begin{Bmatrix}
x-z=0 \\
y=0
\end{Bmatrix}$

$
V_2 \equiv \begin{Bmatrix}
x-2z=0
\end{Bmatrix}$

Find a real $3\times3$ matrix that satisfies such conditions.

**My attempt:**

We shall unite both subspaces: $V=V_1 \cup V_2 \equiv \begin{Bmatrix}
x-z=0 \\
y=0 \\
x-2z=0
\end{Bmatrix} \\$

So, $M_V=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & -2
\end{pmatrix}$

Therefore, we perform the operation: $M_{Sol}=M_VDM_V^{-1}$

$D=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

$M_V^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$

Finally, we calculate: $M_{Sol}=M_VDM_V^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 3 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
$

Although the eigenvalues are the ones asked, the eigenvectors are not. Some of the eigenvectors for this matrix are:

$v_1=(1,0,2)$, $v_2=(1,0,1)$, $v_3=(0,1,0)$

To my knowledge, they should be:

$v'_1=(1,0,-2)$, $v'_2=(1,0,-1)$, $v'_3=(0,1,0)$

Comment: The matrix $M_V$ is not correct : you should find a basis of $V_1$, a basis of $V_2$, and put the three chosen vectors in column.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Why isn't it correct? Doesn't it represent the coefficients of $V$?

Comment: You're right! The matrix should have been: $M_V=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & -2
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: This is still incorrect ! The vector $(1, 0, -2)$ (your third column) belongs neither to $V_1$ nor to $V_2$.

Comment: Isn't the third column representing $x-2z=0$ which belongs to $V_2$?

Comment: For $(x,y,z)=(1,0,-2)$, one has $x-2z=1-2\times(-2)=5 \neq 0$, so this vector does not belong to $V_2$. What you have to put in columns are not the coefficients of the equations defining $V_1$ and $V_2$, but vectors that form a basis of these subspaces.

Comment: Understood, so would $(x,y,z)=(1,0,\frac{1}{2})$ be a vector that belongs to $V_2$ because $x-2z=1-2(\frac{1}{2})=0$?

Comment: Yes, you can choose this vector for $V_2$ (but you also need another one since $\dim(V_2)=2$).

Comment: Would $M_V=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & \frac{1}{2}
\end{pmatrix}$ be a correct solution for the matrix asked? If I'm not wrong it satisfies the equations given.

Comment: Yes, this should work !

Comment: Well, I don't know why but I'm still getting the eigenvectors: $v_1 =(1,0,\frac{1}{2})=(2,0,1), v_2 = (1,0,1), v_3 = (0,1,0)$ Or is it just those which I have to get?

Comment: Well, isn't this what you need ? $v_1$ and $v_3$ form a basis of $V_2$ and $v_2$ forms a basis of $V_1$.

Comment: True that, I was still thinking on the $v'_1, v'_2, v'_3$ vectors I stated in my attempt. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrix $M_V$ is incorrect. It should've been:

$M_V=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & \frac{1}{2}
\end{pmatrix}$

This is because we need vectors that satisfy the systems of equations $V_1$ and $V_2$ given.

Moreover, the vectors need to form basis of $V_1$ and $V_2$ which means you need $1$ vector for $V_1$ and $2$ vectors for $V_2$ as their dimensions are $dim(V_1)=1$ and $dim(V_2)=2$.

Here, we have a graphical representation of $v_1, v_2, v_3$:

[image: Vector representation of v_1, v_2, v_3]